# Fitting a discrete X-axis with factors in R/ggplot2 with levels not preserved in the data set

Tags: r, ggplot2, x-axis

I want to create a group of graphs using RStudio and want the scales to be consistent between all graphs. The graphs were created with the ggplot2 package and the geom_dotplot function. For the x-axis, the values were converted to factors. In the first graph, levels 0-6 are available, but in the second graph (subpopulation of the first group), only groups 1-6 occured in the dataframe (thus, level "0" is not shown). As a result, the scaling of the X-axis of both graphs is not uniform.

I have already tried different approaches to force RStudio to show all levels. Among others I tried the following:

```
scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE, limits=c("0", "6"), breaks=c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

However, it didn't work...

Do you have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you explain or show what didn't work?  Also try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you for the support offered! I have again spent several hours to find the error. In the end, a "+" was missing at the end of the previous command, which is why the above term was not included. Now it works perfectly (so the term was correct in itself).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the support offered! I have again spent several hours to find the error. In the end, a "+" was missing at the end of the previous command, which is why the above term was not included. Now it works perfectly (so the term was correct in itself).